# How to resolve NoSuchFrameException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frame

I am simply trying to access the elements in a frame on the UI. However I am unable to switch to the frame. When I try I get an error "No frame element found by name or id content"
Here is the html:
[image]

And here is the code to access the frame:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  
driver.switchTo().frame("content");
```

It's just a simple switch to frame but am not sure what's going wrong. Appreciate the help.
NOTE: I am using the Chromedriver

Comment: Please add Code as text formatting it as code for advanced highlighting instead of posting pictures of it.

Comment: I understand. However, unfortunately I cant add the actual code here. I would highly appreciate any help if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the "content" IFrame exists when launching the switchTo() function?

Comment: Yes, the frame exists. I first login to the application and after that i am trying to access the frame.